# ELF, PIE ASLR and everything in between, specifically within Linux

Tags: compilation, linker, elf, aslr

Before asking my question, I would like to cover some few technical details I want to make sure I've got correct:

- A Position Independent Executable (PIE) is a program that would be able to execute regardless of which memory address it is loaded into, right?
- ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) pretty much states that in order to keep addresses static, we would randomize them in some manner,

I've read that specifically within Linux and Unix based systems, implementing ASLR is possible regardless of if our code is a PIE, if it is PIE, all jumps, calls and offsets are relative hence we have no problem.
If it's not, code somehow gets modified and addresses are edited regardless of whether the code is an executable or a shared object.

Now this leads me to ask a few questions

1. If ASLR is possible to implement within codes that aren't PIE and are executables AND NOT SHARED / RELOCATABLE OBJECT (**I KNOW HOW RELOCATION WORKS WITHIN RELOCATABLE OBJECTS!!!!**), how is it done? ELF format should hold no section that states where within the code sections are functions so the kernel loader could modify it, right? ASLR should be a kernel functionality so how on earth could, for example, an executable containing, for example, these instructions.

   **pseudo code:**

   ```
    inc_eax:
     add eax, 5
     ret

    main:
     mov eax, 5
     mov ebx, 6
     call ABSOLUTE_ADDRES{inc_eax}
   ```

   How would the kernel executable loader know how to change the
   addresses if they aren't stored in some relocatable table within the ELF
   file and aren't relative in order to load the executable into some
   random address?
2. Let's say I'm wrong, and in order to implement ASLR you must have a
   PIE executable.  All segments are relative. How would one compile a
   C++ OOP code and make it work, for example, if I have some instance
   of a class using a pointer to a virtual table within its struct,
   and that virtual table should hold absolute addresses, hence I
   wouldn't be able to compile a pure PIE for C++ programs that have
   usage of run time virtual tables, and again ASLR isn't possible....
   I doubt  that virtual tables would contain relative addresses and
   there would be a different virtual table for each call of some
   virtual function...
3. My last and least significant question is regarding ELF and PIE — is there some special way to detect an ELF executable is PIE? I'm familiar with the ELF format so I doubt that there is a way, but I might be wrong.  Anyway, if there isn't a way, how does the kernel loader know if our executable is PIE hence it could use ASLR on it.

I've got this all messed up in my head and I'd love it if someone could help me here.

Comment: Derp I have no idea how to resolve my own question yet however I've managed to sort everything within my head and understand it: If someone seems to have a problem similar to mine I highly suggest reading these two articles they've helped me a lot https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/

Answer (score 27):

Your question appears to be a mish-mash of confusion and misunderstanding.

> A Position Independent Executable (PIE) is a program that would be able to execute regardless of which memory address it is loaded into, right?

Almost. A `PIE` binary usually can not be loaded into memory at *arbitrary* address, as its `PT_LOAD` segments will have some alignment requirements (e.g. 0x400, or 0x10000). But it *can* be loaded and will run correctly if loaded into memory at address satisfying the alignment requirements.

> ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) pretty much states that in order to keep addresses static we would randomize them in some manner,

I can't parse the above statement in any meaningful way.

ASLR is a technique for randomizing various parts of address space, in order to make "known address" attacks more difficult.

Note that ASLR *predates* `PIE` binaries, and does not in any way require `PIE`. When ASLR was introduced, it randomized placement of stack, heap, and shared libraries. The placement of (non-`PIE`) main executable could not be randomized.

ASLR has been considered a success, and therefore extended to also support `PIE` main binary, which is really a specially crafted shared library (and has `ET_DYN` file type).

> 1. `call ABSOLUTE_ADDRES{inc_eax}`
>    how would the kernel executable loader know how to change the addresses if > they aren't stored in some relocatable table

Simple: on x86, there is *no* instruction to `call ABSOLUTE_ADDRESS` -- all calls are relative.

> 2 ... I wouldn't be able to compile a pure PIE for C++ programs that have usage of run time virtual tables, and again ASLR isn't possible..

`PIE` binary requires *relocation*, just like a shared library. Virtual tables in `PIE` binaries work *exactly* the same way they work in shared libraries: `ld-linux.so.2` updates `GOT` (global offset table) before transferring control to the `PIE` binary.

> 3 ... is there some special way to detect an ELF executable is PIE

Simple: a `PIE` binary has ELF file type set to `ET_DYN` (a non-`PIE` binary will have type `ET_EXEC`). If you run `file a.out` on a `PIE` executable, you'll see that it's a "shared library".

Comment: if so, how are virtual pointers possible?, what about call far operation within x86....