# Could I load elf and get virtual address from /proc/pid/maps before actually running it?

Tags: c, linux, binary, memory-address, perf

Take a look at how perf works, user can use command like "perf record -e cpu-clock ./binary" to run the binary and get information. Does perf load the binary, make some config and then running it? If it is true, could I get virtual address of some code by looking at the /proc/pid/maps? I am a rookie in binary execution and hope for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could I load elf and get virtual address from /proc/pid/maps before actually running it?

No. The address space is built as the program runs. "Memory mapping" is a *process* (of software being run and requesting memory mappings), not a *property* of the binary file.  This becomes doubly clear now that basically all mainstream operating systems use address space layout randomization (ASLR)!

Often, a lot of that is done *before* your C `main()` even runs - by the loader (`ld.so` on Linux), but that's still *executing code from your binary*.

What your ELF file *does* contain are sections which *can* be loaded at fixed addresses, but as said, ASLR makes that rare. Much of the code compiled these days is *relocateable*, so all it needs is to know is *relative* addresses.

Your question regarding `perf record` is unrelated, but what perf does is set up some kernel-space observables (using, mostly, eBPF) and then quite regularly executing the binary, while probing said observables.

Comment: It is actually possible to get the **virtual** address from the elf header

Comment: @alinsoar hm, in PIE object files, there's no fixed virtual address; it's all relative to values in the global offset table. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189169/elf-pie-aslr-and-everything-in-between-specifically-within-linux

Comment: @alinsoar: yes, for a non-PIE executable, but you of course can't get it from `/proc/<PID>/maps` like the question is asking unless there's a process actually executing this ELF executable.  (You can use `ptrace` to have that process stop before the first user-space instruction, [like GDB uses to implement `starti`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69762022/how-does-gdb-start-an-assembly-compiled-program-and-step-one-line-at-a-time).)

Comment: @Marcus: *by the loader (ld.so on Linux)* - I'm pretty sure the kernel's ELF program loader still maps a dynamic executable as well as the ELF interpeter's (`ld.so`'s) own text/data segments.  If you `strace /bin/true` for example, you see system calls made by `ld.so`, and they don't include `open` / `mmap` of the executable.  Only of `libc.so.6`.  Also, if you use GDB to `starti` on it, you stop before the first instruction of `ld.so`'s `_start`.  And even at that point, you'd see mappings for the program's own segments as well as ld.so in `/proc/<PID>/maps`.

Comment: What `perf record` actually does for hardware PMU events like `cycles` and `instructions` is use `perf_event_open` to have the kernel use HW perf counters.  The kernel saves/restores them on context switch.  Those counters overflow when reaching the programmed point, causing an interrupt or causing the CPU to record a sample into a small buffer (for "precise events" on modern x86).  It's not a matter of asynchronously sampling them, unless you're looking at software events.  Oh, but the question specified `-e cpu-clock` which is software, not `cycles` or `uops_issued.any` or other HW events.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : Thanks for your great answer! By the way, could give me some advice about get the vaddr of some user code after actually running the binary?

Comment: @PeterCordes: **And even at that point, you'd see mappings for the program's own segments as well as ld.so in /proc/<PID>/maps.** So does there exist some easy ways to do such things?

Comment: @qunqunqun: By forking a new process, using `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)`, and execing the executable, yes, like GDB does ([How does gdb start an assembly compiled program and step one line at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69762022)).  It normally makes more sense to just parse the ELF program headers directly out of the binary, though, especially because another run of a PIE executable will randomly choose a different base address.  So you probably want to know whether it's a PIE or not.  Whether any of that is useful depends on what problem you're trying to solve.